# How to remove the ingress delay introduced using tc

Tags: traffic-shaping, tc

I learned that we can introduce delay to ingress packets using tc by following the commands specified in :

> https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem#how_can_i_use_netem_on_incoming_traffic3f
>   **Section**: How can I use netem on incoming traffic?

Commands used for injecting delay:

```
 # modprobe ifb
 # ip link set dev ifb0 up
 # tc qdisc add dev eth0 ingress
 # tc filter add dev eth0 parent ffff: \ 
   protocol ip u32 match u32 0 0 flowid 1:1 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
 # tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root netem delay 750ms
```

But, finding it difficult to revert the system back to normal. Can any one please help me on how to restore the settings?
After executing the commands mentioned above, I see ifb0 on my system. I could remove the delay by executing the following command:

```
sudo tc qdisc del dev ifb0 root netem
```

But, I still see the ifb0 and I believe the traffic is still going through ifb0. I want to delete ifb0 and make the traffic to go through eth0. How may I do that?

I am running commands on Ubuntu 16.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 4):

I figured out the answer.
Following are the sequence of commands to recover.

```
tc qdisc del dev eth0 handle ffff: ingress
modprobe -r ifb
```